# Split String in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I would like to use the MYSQL Stored Procedure to split this input string to insert data to table.
It must group the word.

Input:

> string strTest = **AAA**-1111,AAA-666,SMT-QWQE,SMT-TTTR

Expected output:

> ***Col1,Col2***
>    AAA,1111,
>    AAA,666,
>    SMT,QWQE,
>    SMT,TTTR,

What pattern do I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no split function in mysql but you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function and `replace function` of mysql. More detail about this function is bleow

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php

This will split an IP address ("a.b.c.d") into 4 respective octets:

```
SELECT
   `ip` , 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ip` , '.', 1 ) AS a,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ip` , '.', 2 ),'.',-1) AS b, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ip` , '.', -2 ),'.',1) AS c,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ip` , '.', -1 ) AS d
    FROM log_table
```

Reference link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html